# Regular expression for comma separated, range

Tags: java, regex

I need to create a regular expression for comma separated numbers (maximum 3 digits) and/or ranges separated by dash. The following strings are valid

12
12,13,14,15
12,13-15,16,100-101,120
12-13,15-20,100-200

Note that the numbers cannot be greater than 3 digits.

I need a to validate the string in Java. Any one can please suggest a matching regular expression for these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow upto three digits (1 to 3), use `\d{1,3}` pattern.

```
^\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3})?(?:,\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3})?)*$
```

Java regex would be,

```
"^\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?(?:,\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?)*$"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bK3lB8/1)

```
String s1 = "12,13-15,16,100-101,120";
String s2 = "12,13";
String s3 = "12-13,15-20,100-200";
String s4 = "12-1300,15-20,100-2000";
String s5 = "-13,15-20,100-200";
System.out.println(s1.matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?(?:,\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?)*$"));
System.out.println(s2.matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?(?:,\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?)*$"));
System.out.println(s3.matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?(?:,\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?)*$"));
System.out.println(s4.matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?(?:,\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?)*$"));
System.out.println(s5.matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?(?:,\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?)*$"));
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is already conventional ways to do this posted, this is an alternate way.

```
"^(?!.*-\\d+-)\\d{1,3}(?:[,-]\\d{1,3})*$"

 ^ 
 (?! .* - \d+ - )
 \d{1,3} 
 (?: [,-] \d{1,3} )*
 $
```